# Why are LSTM prediction shape not as expected?

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, lstm, reshape

I am having a time series dataset with the timestamp and one value (in total 2 columns only) and training an LSTM  to predict the values for each hour.

So I prepare the data set to the model is like below :

Take the last 5 previous values of the value as X and observed value for the hour as y.
then I split the train and test for each X and y.

So I have the train and data sets with the below shape after scaling it with a min-max scaler.

```
print(train_X.shape,train_y.shape,test_X.shape,test_y.shape)
(16195, 5) (16195,) (8716, 5) (8716,)
```

then I build the model by

```
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(5, input_shape=(n_steps,n_features),recurrent_dropout=0.2,return_sequences=True))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Dense(1))    
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
```

I fit the model and predict by

```
history = model.fit(train_X, train_y, epochs=10, batch_size=64,validation_data=(test_X, test_y),shuffle=False)


#predict the instances
predicted = model.predict(test_X)
```

I have now predicted in the shape of `(8716, 5, 1)`.

which is not correct I guess because the prediction should be the same as test_y shape which is `(8716,)`.
So when I reshape to inverse scale

```
predicted=yhat.reshape(predicted.shape[0], -1).reshape(-1, 1)
inverse_predictions= scaler_y.inverse_transform(predicted)
```

This gives the shape as `(43580, 1)` which is wrong because the predicted is having the dimension `(8716, 5, 1)` instead of `(8716,)`.

I am not sure which part is causing the error. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete `return_sequences=True`, that should fix the issue.
Alternatively you can use a flattening layer but I don't think this is what you would want to do here.